# Get all array keys where their value occurs more than once in the array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, key, grouping

How can I populate an array of two or more keys that share the same value.

For example this is array:

```
Array
(
   [869] => 87
   [938] => 89
   [870] => 127
   [871] => 127
   [940] => 127
   [942] => 123
   [947] => 123
   [949] => 75
)
```

Values `87`, `89`, and `75` only exist once, so they are excluded from the result.

Values that occur more than once should have their keys grouped into subarrays in the result.

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => array
    (
        [1] => 870
        [2] => 871
        [3] => 940
    )
    [2] => array
    (
        [1] => 942
        [2] => 947
    )
)
```

Comment: do you know the max limit of the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will do what you want. Many not be the simplest it could be but it works:

```
<?php

$myArray = array(
   869 => 87,
   938 => 89,
   870 => 127,
   871 => 127,
   940 => 127,
   942 => 123,
   947 => 123,
   949 => 75
);
$newArray = $foundKeys = array();
$itt = 0;
foreach($myArray as $i => $x){
    foreach($myArray as $j => $y ){
        if($i != $j && !in_array($i,$foundKeys) && $x == $y){
           if(!is_array($newArray[$itt])){
               $newArray[$itt] = array($i);
           }
           array_push($newArray[$itt],$j);
           array_push($foundKeys,$j);
        }
    }
    $itt++;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 870
            [1] => 871
            [2] => 940
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 942
            [1] => 947
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to do if your second array had the value you're checking for as it's key e.g.

```
Array
(
    [127] => array
    (
        [1] => 870
        [2] => 871
        [3] => 940
    )
    [123] => array
    (
        [1] => 942
        [2] => 947
    )
)
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
<?php

$output = array();
foreach($your_array as $key => $current) {
    if( !array_key_exists($current, $output) ) {
        // create new entry
        $output[$current] = array( $key );
    } else {
        // add to existing entry
        $output[$current][] = $key;
    }
}

print_r($output);
?>
```

This should return the output above...

Comment: I have edited the previously unedited question to clarify the original logical requirements.   Your answer does not deliver the desired result. If it was correct, `$output[$current][] = $key;` would be all that was needed in the loop body -- declaring the parent element is not necessary when pushing children with square brace syntax. (as in sectus's answer)

Answer (score 1):

My short code.

```
$array =Array
(
   869 => 87,
   938 => 89,
   870 => 127,
   871 => 127,
   940 => 127,
   942 => 123,
   947 => 123,
   949 => 75
);

$return = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    $return[$value][] = $key;

var_dump(array_values($return));
```

http://3v4l.org/scDZ4

Comment: will throw undefined index errors if error reporting is cranked up, but nice otherwise ;)

Comment: @scrowler, are you sure?

Comment: Ya, it's normally a good idea to define variables before you use them just in case, but most of the time you won't encounter those errors on a live server

Comment: I can see that. Try it on a server with `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`

Comment: @scrowler, I am always work with `error_reporting=-1`. You should check it yourself. Also look at last line of this example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-95

Comment: This answer will not generate any warnings/notices/errors. When pushing with square brace syntax, parent elements do not need to be declared before pushing children. That said, it does not deliver the desired result, it is missing its plain English explanation, and it is not PSR-12 compliant because the `foreach()` is missing its curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of whether a value has occurred zero, one, or more times.

- On the first encounter, save the value and key in a temporary array for easy future reference.
- On the second occurrence, push the the associative value from the temporary array into the result array, then push the current iteration's value and key as well.
- On any further encounters of the same value, do not bother pushing the first encounter into the result (although you could replace the null coalescing assignment operator with a simple assignment operator in this case) and just push the current value and key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/plmtb)) or without `??=` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eCXRt))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (!isset($found[$v])) {
        $found[$v] = $k;
    } else {
        $result[$v][0] ??= $found[$v];
        $result[$v][] = $k;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

I am using `array_values()` to remove the first level keys in the result.  I am assuming that it is unimportant to the asker and most future researchers to start the numeric keys from `1`.