# Say how many items are the same in 2 arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is there a way within PHP and MySQL to be able to compare 2 different array (list) variables and say how many items are the same

For example,

```
$array1 = "hello, bye, google, laptop, yes";
$array2 = "google, bye, windows, no, phone";
```

Then an echo statement would say how many items are the same. In this example, it would be 2 and this would be echoed.

This is different to most array questions because of the way my site is set up using commas which can make it quite complicated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all array keys with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507065/how-to-get-all-array-keys-with-same-value)

Comment: I can't see that this has much to do with MySQL

Comment: @somerandomgizza check my answer below

Comment: Sorry @Strawberry it is because the array comes from a MySQL database but of course it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to convert your string to array with trim. Then use 
`array_intersect` to get common values.

```
$array1 = "hello, bye, google, laptop, yes";
$array2 = "google, bye, windows, no, phone";
$array_new1 = array_map('trim', explode(',', $array1));
$array_new2 =array_map('trim', explode(',', $array2));
$common = array_intersect($array_new1, $array_new2);
print_r($common);
echo count($common);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `array_intersect()` function in php

```
<?php

$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");

$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r(count($result));
?>
```

You can count elements in the output array using `count()` function,

[doc link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$array_new1  = explode(',',$array1);
$array_new2  = explode(',',$array2);

    $array_1 = array_map('trim', $array_new1);
    $array_2 = array_map('trim', $array_new2);

$data =array();
 foreach($array_2 as $value){ 
     if(in_array($value,$array_1)){    
       $data[] = $value; 
     } 
 }
  echo count($data);
```